# C# Saving Permanent Data in ProgramFiles

Tags: c#, winforms, file, security, directory

I am creating a desktop app that needs to save permanent data. The easiest way I could think of doing this is by writing important information about the file to a textfile. Just to make the data contained, professional and easily accessed by the app, I decided to put it in a newly created folder in the "Program Files" directory  of the users computer. Unfortunately, this is blocked by the computer. It denies the access to my application. I know my code works because I ran the application as an administrator and encountered no errors. It also created the folder in "Program Files" as I wanted. Is there anyway to allow access. I'd also like to get the users' permission first. The code is posted below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyAppNameSpace
{
    static class DataManager
    {
        /* Create a dictionary that takes type "string" for its 
         * key (name) and type "object" for its value */
         public static Dictionary<string, object> Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
         public static string FileName { get; private set; }
         public static string ProgramFilesFolder;

         // A method to clear all game data
         public static void Clear()
         {
         }

         public static void Save()
         {
             foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> DataPair in Data)
             {

             }
         }

         public static string GetData()
         {
             return File.ReadAllText(FileName);
         }

         public static void Setup()
         {
             ProgramFilesFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "/MyAppName";
        FileName = ProgramFilesFolder + "/MyAppData";
             if (!Directory.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "/MyAppName/README.txt"))
             {
                 try
                 {
                     Directory.CreateDirectory(ProgramFilesFolder);
                     string text = "DO NOT move this folder. If you must, make sure to keep it " +
                    "in the same location as the SwingState it is. Also, do not edit the " +
                    "contents of the data file, which exists in this directory. " + 
                    "This saves all of your progress in your game!";
                File.WriteAllText(ProgramFilesFolder + "/README.txt", text);
            }

                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ":" + ex.InnerException);
                     GameInfo.Game.Close();
                 }
            }

            if (!File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { "Name:", null + "," },
                    { "Age:", null + "," },
                    { "Description:", null + "," },
                    { "Gender:", null + "," },
                    { "Level:", 1 + "," },
                    { "Drawing:", false + "," },
                    { "Uploaded:", false + "," },
                    { "Template:", false + "," },
                    { "Left1:", null + "," },
                    { "Left2:", null + "," },
                    { "Left3:", null + "," },
                    { "Right1:", null + "," },
                    { "Right2:", null + "," },
                    { "Right3:", null + "," },
                    { "Idle:", null + "," },
                    { "Template Number:", null + "," }
                 };
            }

            else if (File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                string[] DataText = File.ReadAllText(FileName).Split(',');
                foreach (string s in DataText)
                {
                    Data.Add(s.Split(':')[0], s.Split(':')[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the AppData folder is a common place for application data.

Comment: I don't believe that would give me priveleges, either.

Comment: That is the reason the folder exists, did you try it?

Comment: Just tried it. It's not giving any errors, but the folder isn't showing up.

Comment: Its a hidden folder. Do you need the user to access it or just the application?

Comment: I don't want the user to access it. I'll check now

Comment: I changed it to "Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData" and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the special folder to AppData. Here is the code for that:

```
ProgramFilesFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "/MyAppName";
FileName = ProgramFilesFolder + "/MyAppData";
if (!Directory.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "/MyAppName/README.txt"))
```